# CMLogItem timestamp: Why so complicated?

Tags: swift, core-motion

I receive a `CMLogItem` from a CoreMotion query in swift (could be accelerometer, gyroscope). Now, I want to get the timestamp of that sample, preferably as a Date() object. `CMLogItem`s have a property `.timestamp` of type `TimeInterval`.

The documentation tells me the following:

> The CMLogItem class defines a read-only timestamp property that
>   records the time a motion-event measurement was taken.

However, I am not sure how to convert this timestamp to a Date() object because I dont know what the timestamp is referring to.

Another documentation says:

> The timestamp is the amount of time in seconds since the device
>   booted.

But this seems really weird and I dont understand why apple would create such an inconsistent and complicated API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proper answer is:

```
extension CMLogItem {
    static let bootTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime)

    func startTime() -> Date {
        return CMLogItem.bootTime.addingTimeInterval(self.timestamp)
    }
}
```

This gives us stable, monotonic results, which is not a case, when bootTime is computed every time startTime is called.

Comment: Yup, that's a great idea! Just FYI, this is iOS-only, on watchOS the timeStamp is calculated differently:
`return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: self.timestamp)`

Comment: @DeveloBär What you are saying about watchOS is wrong, it doesn't work like that. I implemented your approach and found that differences between current iPhone timestamp and current watchOS timestamp was around 900,000,000 seconds.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. It worked for the first time. But in production when the app was used for a while, and the device was sleeping for a while the next time the timestamp is off.. I'm pretty sure the `bootTime` has to be refreshed every time the app is getting awaken.. not only the first time..

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out.
The documentation is just wrong here.
It is not the "time in seconds since the device booted" — it is indeed the time since their reference date.

Fix:

```swift
extension CMLogItem {
    func startTime() -> Date {
        #if os(watchOS)
        return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: self.timestamp)
        #else
        let systemRebootTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime)
        return systemRebootTime.addingTimeInterval(self.timestamp)
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: wrong. Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: ) Creates a date value initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001 by a given number of seconds.

Comment: Soo please elaborate how this is wrong? The timestamps seem to be relative to the 2001 reference date?!

Comment: This is wrong, because the `timestamp` on `CMLogItem` is not relative to reference date, which is a date on 1st of January 2001, but is relative to the time device booted.

Comment: edited the code above. this is on watchOS only. on iOS it seems to be using the time since the last restart.

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives huge differences in time. What is more, there is much more complicated relation between timestamp on watchOS and iPhone. It seems it takes into account how long device is in sleep state.

Comment: OK, my claim that relation between watchOS and iOS timestamps are correlated to how long device is in sleep state is NOT TRUE. I've got other problems connected to  cluttering processing queue and handlers was lagged.